# CHIP-8 delay timer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

I'm writing a CHIP-8 emulator in C++, which has [two timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8#Timers). If these timers are non-zero, they are decremented by 1 at 60Hz. I'm still getting the hang of C++, so I wanted to see if I'm doing this the Right Way.

Here's the header file:

```
#include <chrono>

struct TimedRegister
{
  unsigned char value;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> last_write;

  TimedRegister();
  void set(const unsigned char new_value);
  void decrement();
};
```

And this is the the implementation:

```
#include "chip8.hpp"

#include <chrono>

TimedRegister::TimedRegister()
  : value(0)
{}

void
TimedRegister::set(const unsigned char new_value)
{
  value = new_value;
  last_write = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

void
TimedRegister::decrement()
{
  if (value == 0)
    return;

  const auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - last_write)
        .count() >= 1000 / 60) {
    --value;
    last_write = now;
  }
}
```

The `decrement` function is called from the main emulator loop like this:

```
while (!chip8.halted) {
  chip8.delay_timer.decrement();
}
```

They seem to work fine, but I'm not sure if I'm getting away with using a heavy-handed, brute-force approach.

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated, but ideally you should be updating the timers while refreshing the screen, like the original interpreter does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When doing emulation you should disconnect from the real world and only provide a abstract view to a world.

In other words don't use a real time clock instead simulate the timer by linking it to the emulated clockspeed. For example if you pick 8 MHz you would have 133 333 instructions executed per decrement of each timer.

This will allow you to pause and fast forward when debugging programs.

Comment: For Chip8, the timer should be cued off display refresh.  If memory serves, vintage Chip8 implementations run roughly 1800 cycles (900 two-cycle instructions) between frames, but some operations like draw sprite wait for the next refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Some minor observations:

- Make the code easier to read
  Long lines including `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and `std::chrono::milliseconds` might be a good choice for applying the `using` directive:
  `using high_res_clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;`
  You can then use `high_res_clock` instead of the unwieldy old term.
- Use compiler warnings
  Always enable as many warning flags as possible. That way the compiler can help you eliminate possible errors. In this case you should initialize `last_write` just like you do with `value`.
- `class` VS. `struct`
  I'm unsure how this ties into the rest of your code but I was taught to use `struct` for PODs and `class` if you have methods. Just remember that in classes everything is private by default unlike in structs where it's the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Since you keep a note of `last_write`, you don't need to keep updating the actual value.

Instead, implement a `read()` overload that *computes* the value as seen by the emulated system:

```
unsigned char TimedRegister::read()
{
    if (!value)
        return 0;

    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<Chip8::Tick>(now - last_write);
    if (elapsed.count() > value)
        // assign to value, so we don't look at clock next time
        return value = 0;

    return value - elapsed.count();
}
```

I'd consider moving away from `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` for this - you really want your own emulated-system clock, which you can advance under program control.  That will make both unit-testing and debugging easier.